# SEF Joomla not working if page not exist (404)

Tags: php, nginx, joomla

I have a server with Centos 6.5, Joomla and Nginx. All works fine, and I enabled SEF in joomla to use friendly URL's, like :

```
example.com/the-­news/1­-latest-­news/1-­welcome-­to­-joomla.
```

In nginx vhost example.conf, i put the line:

```
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
```

This works great, BUT if i enter some URL than not exist, like `example.com/asdasdasd`, so I'm redirected to the main page, the index (example.com) but I'm to show the joomla default 404 error page, not redirect to the index page.

Someone knows how to do it ?

Thanks all!

Comment: So you are saying you should be getting a 404 but you are redirecting to the home page instead? (This is the opposite of what people usually ask.)

Comment: Yes Elin, i want to show the template 404 error, not redirect to home page. If SEF is disabled, this works, but SEF redirect to main page, i dont know why and how :/

Answer (score 0):

You can force to load your 404 page by .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php
```

Put it on top of your .htaccess file

EDIT: Replace `http://yourdomain.com/404.php`  with your joomla 404 URL.

Comment: In joomla + nginx i can use .htaccess ?

Comment: You can convert it. Use this instruction:    `#nginx configuration
error_page 404 http://yourdomain.com/404.php;`

Comment: You can not you .htaccess with nginx. This is wrong.

Comment: I didnt specifically say it works with nginx, and  provided the configuration instruction for nginx. You can convert any htaccess to nginx instructions : http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: I think your problem is with joomla, not with nginx. You need to pass the args to index.php, and you do it well, but joomla is no redirecting to the 404 page. I have work with joomla and nginx and I have never configured nginx for returning the 404, joomla does. Can you check if do `curl -I http://example.com/asdasdasd` if you receive a 404 or 301 code??

Comment: Joomla templates have error pages built in so you wouldn't use 404.php.

Comment: AGL, i did via ssh and the return code was 303. BUT, if i put asdasd.php, the code was 404. i agree the error can be in joomla, and in templates, and i have the error.php in templates/yoo_nano3/error.php - is this file called when SEF is disabled. so, if nginx redirect non existent urls to Index, the index must check and redirect to this file, or something like that. right ?